# Robojuice / Butterknife @InjectView AutoFormatting issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I am adopting the `@InjectView` theme throughout my project and have a minor issue when it comes to condensing these declarations.  After I put in the initial code it looks great in one line like this..

`@InjectView(R.id.tv_report_summary_name) TextView tvReportSummaryName;`

However if I do an auto format (Ctrl + Shift + F), Android Studio is automatically replacing this with two lines so it looks like:

```
@InjectView(R.id.tv_report_summary_name)                                     
TextView tvReportSummaryName;
```

Is there a way to avoid this or modify my formatting options to make this not happen?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you open **Preferences -> Code Style -> Java**.

Choose Tab **Wrapping and Braces**.

After that scroll to bottom and there is option to set this style as is shown in the image below:

[image]

Choose which is wright for you.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you

Answer (score 4):

Follow this :

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -- Field Annotation and select the checkbox (Do not wrap after single annotation)

Hopefully, it will solve your problem.